# Remove first elements in a nested list in F#?

Tags: f#

I want to remove the first elements from a nested list. I've just learned about List.map and List.filter, but I can't get it to work.

So [ [1;2;3]; [4;5;6] ] gets to be [ [2;3]; [5;6 ]

Can anyone hint me in the right direction?

Version 1:

```
let remove l =

for i in l do
    printfn "i %A" i
    for j in i do 
        printfn "%A" j
        List.map (fun x -> x) j


printfn "done"


printfn "%A" (remove ([[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]]))
```

Version 2:

```
let remove1 l = 

  for i in l do
     printfn "i %A" i
     List.map (fun x -> x.[2..]) j


printfn "%A" (remove1 ([[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]]))
```

I know both of them are wrong somehow, I just wanted to show that I am at least trying and not just asking to get a quick answer.

Regards

Comment: It's not clear from your question how you pick which element you want to remove. Is it by index ("the first element of the second list")? Or is it by value (remove the number 5 from wherever it appears)?

Comment: Sorry, it should be the first element of each sub-list, I corrected the topic so it makes it more clear.

Comment: Check out `List.tail`, which takes a list and returns the list minus its first element. Then map that function across the outer list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `for ... do`, but that's for imperative code (e.g., for every element in a list, perform this side effect).

What you want is a function that takes in a list, and returns a list where each item has been transformed. (Here, the items are sublists and the transformation is "remove first item from the list"). That's what `List.map` is for: `List.map transformation lst` will take the list `lst`, run the transformation across each item, and create a new list with the values returned from the transformation. (The transformation should be a function that takes the original item and returns the new value).

Now, as we've said, the transformation you want to apply is to take a list and return it minus its first item. That could be expressed as `fun lst -> List.tail lst`, so your map would look like `List.map (fun innerList -> List.tail innerList) outerList`. However, any time you see `fun x -> someFun x`, that expression can be simply replaced by `someFun`. So that `List.map` call becomes simply:

```
List.map List.tail outerList
```

Or, expressed as a function:

```
let removeFirst outerList = List.map List.tail outerList
```

And here we can use a programming style called "point-free" style (unless you're familiar with lambda calculus, the "point-free" name might be confusing, so think of it as "parameter-free" style) to simplify that expression even more:

```
let removeFirst = List.map List.tail
```

And so we've arrived at the (quite correct) solution that @dumetrulo posted. However, for a beginner, "point-free" style might be confusing, so I'd recommend being a bit more explicit about your parameters so that when you read this code later, you realize that `removeFirst` is a function, not a value. Therefore I'd recommend writing your function as:

```
let removeFirst outerList = List.map List.tail outerList
```

Comment: As usual, rmunn I learn so much from your answers. And thank you for explaining me how to see it functionally!

Comment: So a lambda can be removed if it takes no arguments, got it!

Comment: "If it takes no arguments" isn't quite the right way to phrase it, because there's no such thing as a lambda that takes no arguments in F#. (Writing `fun -> ...` would produce a syntax error). Rather, a lambda can be removed if it does nothing but call another function. `fun x -> someFun x` means "create an anonymous function taking one parameter, that just calls `someFun` with that parameter and returns its result". That anonymous function is totally equivalent to `someFun`, so why the extra step? Just call `someFun` directly. So `fun x -> someFun x` is always equivalent to `someFun`.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a list of lists, and want to remove the first element of each sublist. If we assume that all sublists have at least 1 element, we can use `List.tail` on each sublist to get its tail (i.e. the list without the first element), then use it as the mapper function mapping over the outer list with `List.map`:

```
let removeFirst = List.map List.tail
```

Yes, it's really that simple!

Comment: For anyone who gets `error FS0030: Value restriction`, make the parameter explicit (`let removeFirst l = List.map List.tail l` as in rmunn's answer).  The cause of the error is beyond the scope of a comment; there are plenty of other resources if you want to delve into what that error means.

Comment: I'll go for rmunn's answer as he explains in details what is going on step by step. This is very useful for people with little experience! Thank you for taking the time though